# exception in if statement

Tags: ruby, if-statement, for-loop, each

I wrote a searcher function in ruby for a class that iterates on a list of people (named @personList).
It faces an exception.

My Code‌ :

```
def search (nCode)
    for x in @personList
        if x.nCode == nCode 
            x.to_s
    end
end
```

I wrote the same code using **each**, it also faced the same exception.
What's wrong with my code ?
(I'm new to Ruby! and I couldn't solve that)

Comment: Please add what things @personList contains.

Comment: And provide the specific details of your exception.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This `if` is delimited by a pair of newlines:

```
x.to_s if x.nCode == nCode
```

This `if` needs an explicit `end`:

```
if x.nCode == nCode 
    x.to_s
end
```

You have opened three blocks (`def`, `for..in`, `if`) in your first sample, but only closed two. Your indentation indicates the `if` is the one you didn't close. Thus, you have a syntax error. Otherwise, both samples are identical in functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby `if` requires an `end` to make it complete. If you use end for your exception code, it will work.

```
if x.nCode == nCode 
    x.to_s
end
```

For second case, that worked or you, it is actually completes the condition and the execution in one line. That's why it didn't require any `end`, and it worked for you.

You'll find more detail about `if` from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_if_else.htm).